# How are asymptotes actually defined in rigorous mathematics?

Tags: definition, analytic-geometry

This question is coming from the analytic geometry viewpoint. Please ignore the viewpoint of algebraic geometry here, unless that viewpoint is somehow able to handle non-algebraic curves like $x \mapsto e^x$ etc. which I don't think it is.

According to my Year 12 mathematics textbook, an asymptote is:

> A line that approaches a curve but does not touch it.

With the benefit of the modern viewpoint, this definition just *feels* very weird and 18th Century, for the following reason: to "approach a curve" is to be somehow "close to it"; but, according to the above definition, if we get *so* close to the curve that we actually *intersect* it, then we're "too close" and its no longer an asymptote. Presumably, this isn't desirable, and so the hope is that modern authors no longer include this condition in their definition of "asymptote."

A moment of Googling brings up the relevant Wikipedia page:

> In analytic geometry, an asymptote of a curve is a line such that the
>   distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as they tend
>   to infinity. Some sources include the requirement that the curve may not cross the line infinitely often, but this is unusual for modern authors.

Okay, this is definitely making a lot more sense. But, I still think a few things are screwy. Firstly, there are different definitions of curves lying about, and they aren't completely consistent. So lets just get rid of any mention of curves at all. We obtain:

> Let $A$ denote a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then an *asymptote* of $A$ is a line such that the distance between $A$ and the line approaches zero as they tend to infinity.

Alright. Its still imprecise. Notice we haven't told the reader *what* exactly is approaching infinity. There's at least two ways of resolving this ambiguity, and they result in two fundamentally different notions of "asymptote."

> **Asymptote, Undirected Version.** Let $A$ denote a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then an *asymptote* of $A$ is a line $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that for all $l \in L$, if $d(l,0)>r$, then the distance $d(l,A)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

For example, the function $x \mapsto e^{-x^2}$ has precisely **one** asymptote according this definition. And the function $x \mapsto e^x$ has no asymptotes at all.

There's also another possible way of resolving the ambiguity. First, we need an auxiliary definition.

> **Directed Line.** A *directed line* in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a function $c : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that:
>
> - $c$ is injective
> - $c$ preserves convex combinations: that is, for all $a,b \in [0,\infty)$ satisfying $a+b=1,$ we have $c(ap+bq) = ac(p)+bc(q).$
>
> Two directed lines are said to be *equal* iff they intersect at more than one point.

We can then define asymptote like so:

> **Asymptote, Directed Version.** Let $A$ denote a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then an *asymptote* of $A$ is a directed line $c : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, there exists $t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that for all $t' \geq t$, the distance $d(c(t'),A)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

For example, the previously-mentioned function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ has precisely **two** asymptotes according this definition. And the function $x \mapsto e^x$ has precisely one asymptote.

Now clearly, the undirected definition is easier to state. But I feel the the directed one is more useful. Anyway, my question is simple:

> **Question.** How are asymptotes *actually* defined in rigorous mathematics?
>
> I am not suggesting that there can be only one definition. If multiple definitions are useful, then I'd like to know about all of them. Thanks.

Comment: I've personally never seen a definition of asymptote for anything else than the graph of a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "Asymptote, Undirected Version." looks a bit weird. Where do you use $r$?

Comment: @ColmBhandal, thanks! Both definitions were broken hehe. I think they're fixed now.

Comment: @Siminore, I'm not quite sure what you mean, but note that $x \mapsto 1/x$ does not define a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ under the usual definitions, because functions are by definition total. Even putting this aside though, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Most people would probably say that $x \mapsto 1/x$ has both $\{(x,y) \mid x=0\}$ and $\{(x,y) \mid y=0\}$ as asymptotes. Are you saying that, under your preferred defintions, the first of these isn't a "real" asymptote?

Comment: My notation intended to denote "real functions of a real variable", sorry for the confusion. In my experience $x \mapsto 1/x$ has exactly two asymptotes: $x=0$ and $y=0$. I have never seen a definition of asymptote for an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Your directed definition recalls of the definition of oblique asymptote, anyway.

Comment: @Siminore, okay, I see what you mean. Honestly I think that subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the right viewpoint here, for the following reason: if you rotate a function about the origin, it needn't remain a function; but, obviously, its asymptotes should rotate with it.

Comment: But, without any restriction on the subsets, every line is an asymptote of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which doesn't seem very useful. It may be worth paying that price if characterising "sufficiently curve-like" subsets is too cumbersome.

Comment: @DanielFischer, this just comes back to the need to find out how asymptotes are *actually* used in *rigorous* mathematics. It may be that having "too many" asymptotes isn't a problem, or it may be that it *is* a problem. Imo we cannot expect ourselves to figure out whether or not this is a problem with only a few minutes (or hours) thought.

Comment: @goblin Let me ask a question. Consider the set $\{(x,x \sin x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Would you like to give $y=x$ and $y=-x$ any role?

Comment: @Siminore, my intuition says they aren't really asymptotes, they're just upper and lower bounds. This is consistent with the "directed" definition. On the other hand, my intuition also says that $x \mapsto x \sin (x^2)$ has no asymptotes. However, this is inconsistent with the "directed" definition

Comment: I like your "curve-free" definition, but I'm not sure whether asymptotes *are* commonly used (or even used at all) in modern mathematical research.

Comment: In your directed line definition, should the f's be c's?

Comment: @snulty, thanks, fixed. For the record, I'm profoundly dissatisfied with my directed line definition (even the fixed one!). Its just something quick and dirty I threw together for the question. Presumably, there a better, sleeker definitions of "directed line" available.

Comment: @goblin if you're trying to get half lines why not say, if it starts at a point $p$ in the direction of $q$, with $p,q \in \Bbb R^2$, it's the function $c:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$, $c(t)=p+t\cdot q$, which uses the vector space structure of $\Bbb R^2$. Or is it more general than that?

Comment: @snulty, yeah, it's the same thing. The dissatisfaction is mainly in the phrase: "Two directed lines are said to be equal iff they intersect at more than one point." These kinds of definitions make mathematics more painful than it needs to be.

Comment: @goblin You know if you modify the answer I presented you could change it from curves as functions to arbitrary unbounded sets. Just change from $A\subset \Bbb R$ to $A\subset \Bbb R^2$, and drop the mention of $c$ entirely?

Comment: Notice that, under your tentative definitions, the function $\sin(1/x)/x$ has (if I'm not mistaken) a vertical asymptote at $x=0$, which does not agree with common definitions (vertical asymptote $\iff$ $\lim f= \pm \infty$). I'm guessing that it's almost desperate to look for rigourous (and widely accepted) definitions of asymptotes because they hardly belong to "rigorous mathematics".

Comment: @leonbloy, woah! That's now my favorite function :)

Comment: @goblin Inspired by this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863341/if-fx-has-a-vertical-asymptote-does-fx-have-one-too/1863412#1863412

Answer (score 2):

How does the following work. Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ be an interval and $c: A \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ continuous such that $c(A)$ is unbounded in the sense of the usual metric $d$ on $\Bbb R^2$. We can certainly find a sequence $a_n$ in $A$ such that for each $r>0,\,\exists N \in \Bbb N$  such that for $n>N$ we have $c(a_n) \not\in B_{r}((0,0))$. Now let $L\subset \Bbb R^2$ be a line, we say $L$ is an asymptote to $c$ if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathrm{inf}\{d(c(a_n),l)\mid l\in L\}=0$, for a sequence $a_n$ as defined above.

**Note** you then add restrictions on how many times the curve is allowed to intersect a Line. Otherwise a Line is an asymptote to itself, and in fact any line is an asymptote to a spiral centered at the origin, eg Archimedean spiral.

Comment: Obviously, this is more sensible and better behaved than either of the two definitions that I give. However, I'm looking for *accepted* definitions here, not innovative or clever guesses at what the definition should be based on a few minutes or hours of thought. I'm not saying that I want this deleted (I most certainly don't), but I *am* saying that this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I understand your point! I agree it doesn't really answer the question asked. However, a scan for asymptotes gives the following arrive paper about generalised asymptotes, where you allow the asymptote to be a curve rather than a line. @goblin - http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.6153.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be more what you're interested in [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1944-056-00/S0002-9947-1944-0010976-2/S0002-9947-1944-0010976-2.pdf). The author is Herbert Busemann, and the paper is on Local Metric Geometry, and he mentions asymptotes in metric spaces, where the distance is not necessarily symmetric, and according to the reference [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178244920) on project Euclid, by Nasu, he says the concept of asymptotes was introduced. Check his references 2 and 3. That's one of them but I couldn't find the acta math one

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.